# Returning a new structure with fields changed

Tags: common-lisp, immutability, records, shallow-copy

I'm looking for a simple way to return a new structure which is a copy of an existing one with some fields changed, without modifying the original.

I get that you can use `setf` to change the data in one of the fields, like so:

```
[1]> (defstruct foo bar)
FOO
[1]> (defvar quux (make-foo :bar 12))
QUUX
[1]> (foo-bar quux)
12
[1]> (setf (foo-bar quux) 15)
15
[1]> (foo-bar quux)
15
```

But as I stated, this essentially destroys the original data, which isn't what I'm going for.

I could of course do something like this:

```
(defstruct foo bar baz) ; define structure
(defvar quux (make-foo :bar 12 :baz 200)) ; make new instance
(defvar ping (copy-foo quux)) ; copy instance
(setf (foo-bar ping) 15) ; change the bar field in ping
```

But it seems more like a work-around than anything.

In Erlang you can do something like this:

```erlang
-record(foo, {bar, baz}). % defines the record

example() ->
  Quux = #foo{bar = 12, baz = 200}, % creates an instance of the record
  Ping = Quux#foo{bar = 15}. % creates a copy with only bar changed
```

No data modified.

PS Yes I'm aware that Common Lisp isn't Erlang; but Erlang made it convenient to work with records/structures immutably, and since functional style is encouraged in Common Lisp, it would be nice if there was a similar option available.

Comment: “Since functional style is encouraged in Common Lisp”: actually I think we can say that Common Lisp is agnostic about functional style, and in particular the CLOS (object-oriented part in Common Lisp) is completely based on side-effects.

Comment: It's possible to do OOP immutably

Comment: Of course it is possible. But Common Lisp has a set of operators that allows the modification of running systems (for instance changes in a class automatically modifies the instances already created), and this has always been considered as a “bonus” of Common Lisp with respect to other languages. I do not want to say that functional style is not possible neither is a good style: it is an excellent style of programming I only note that I've never seen in Common Lisp something that “encourage” functional style more then imperative style: for this reason I think CL is agnostic with respect to it.

Comment: I mostly base this info off of land of lisp, which in one of the early chapters says functional style is preferred when writing lisp code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erlang [records](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html) are similar to Prolog structures. The Prolog I know implements this as a predicate named [`update_struct/4`](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termmanip/update_struct-4.html) which admits a macro expansion: it takes a type parameter and expands into two unifications. The same kind of processing is done in Erlang, according to the documentation. In Common Lisp, we don't need to pass the type explicitly, as shown with the following `update-struct` function:

```
(defun update-struct (struct &rest bindings)
  (loop
    with copy = (copy-structure struct)
    for (slot value) on bindings by #'cddr
    do (setf (slot-value copy slot) value)
    finally (return copy)))
```

#### Example

```
CL-USER> (defstruct foo bar baz)
FOO
CL-USER> (defparameter *first* (make-foo :bar 3))
*FIRST*
CL-USER> (defparameter *second* (update-struct *first* 'baz 2))
*SECOND*
CL-USER> (values *first* *second*)
#S(FOO :BAR 3 :BAZ NIL)
#S(FOO :BAR 3 :BAZ 2)
```

#### Specification

Rainer Joswig kindly pointed out that:

> There is one thing which is undefined by the standard: using SLOT-VALUE on structure objects is undefined. But it should work on most implementations, as they provide this feature. The only implementation where it does not seem to work is GCL.

Indeed, the HyperSpec says about [`SLOT-VALUE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_slt_va.htm):

> Note in particular that the behavior for conditions and structures is not specified.

An implementation might behave differently if the structured is backed by a list or vector (see the ̀`:TYPE` option). Anyway, if you need to be portable  you'd better use classes. 
This topic was also explained in detail by Rainer in [*common lisp: slot-value for defstruct structures*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17249344/124319).

#### Other immutable data-structures

Consider also using property lists, which play nicely with an immutable approach.

Say your initial list `x` is:

```
(:a 10 :b 30)
```

Then `(list* :b 0 x)` is the following list:

```
(:b 0 :a 10 :b 30)
```

... where the most recent value associated with `:b` shadows the ones after (see [`GETF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm)).

#### Loop details

The `bindings` list is a *property list*, with alternation of keys and values (like keyword parameters).
In the [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) expression above, I am iterating over the list of bindings using `ON`, which means that I am considering each sublist instead of each element. In other words `(loop for x on '(a b c d))` successively binds `x` to `(a b c d)`, `(b c d)`, `(c d)` and finally `(c)`.

However, since I provide a custom `BY` argument, the next element is computed using [`CDDR`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm), instead of the default `CDR` (so, we advance by two cells instead of by one).
That allows me to consider each pair of key/value elements in the list, and bind them to `slot` and `value` thanks to the destructuring syntax.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you're doing in that loop? I can't seem to decode it

Comment: Super clever solution with the explanation. Had no idea generic struct functions existed either! Thanks!

Comment: There is one thing which is undefined by the standard: using `SLOT-VALUE` on structure objects is undefined. But it should work on most implementations, as they provide this feature. The only implementation where it does **not** seem to work is GCL.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks a lot.