# Nondestructive setf?

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp, setf

Common Lisp seems to go to great lengths to provide both nondestructive functions (like subst & remove) and destructive functions and modify macros (like delete & rotatef) for general use. Presumably this is to effectively support both functional and nonfunctional styles of programming. But there also seems to be a particular bias toward the nonfunctional style in the design of the ubiquitous `setf`. The `setf` macro, incorporating  generalized reference, is apparently flexible enough to modify any specifiable place (except perhaps for immutable integers and characters). This power probably accounts for its widespread useage in spite of its nonfunctional/destructive behavior.

The question is why there is not a corresponding "functional style" nondestructive operator, patterned after `setf` (call it put, since `set` is already taken), analogous to other nondestructive/destructive lisp operator pairs. Such an operator would probably take the same arguments, a place and a value, but would return a copy of the object in which the place was embedded, instead of the new value at that place. It also would probably involve a universal copier of some sort, with the standard `setf` simply modifying the copy before returning it. The nondestructive operator then could be used in lieu of `setf` for most assignments, with `setf` being reserved for really large objects. Is such an operator feasible (or even possible) given the (presumed) requirement for a universal copier and the need to recover an object from an arbitrary place embedded in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal setter either, but with SETF you are supposed to provide one when you use [DEFINE-SETF-EXPANDER](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_3.htm). I suppose you could define the equivalent of [lenses/functional references](https://www21.in.tum.de/teaching/fp/SS15/papers/17.pdf). For another approach, Clojure defines an [update](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update) function (borrowed from other languages, I know it exists in Prolog), which is not universal either. The [FSET](https://github.com/slburson/fset) library provides some functional structures, notably associative maps which work like the ones in Clojure.

Suppose for a moment you limit yourself to structures:

```
(defstruct foo a b c)
(defstruct bar x y z)

(defparameter *test*
  (make-foo :a (make-bar :x 0 :y 0 :z 0)
            :b 100
            :c "string"))

;; *test* is now
;; #S(FOO :A #S(BAR :X 0 :Y 0 :Z 0) :B 100 :C "string")
```

The following approach makes a copy, it relies on `copy-structure` and `slot-value`, which, while not standard, is [well supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247540/common-lisp-slot-value-for-defstruct-structures):

```
(defun update (structure keys value)
  (if (endp keys)
      value
      (destructuring-bind (key &rest keys) keys
        (let ((copy (copy-structure structure)))
          (setf (slot-value copy key)
                (update (slot-value copy key)
                         keys
                         value))
          copy))))
```

You can update `*test*` as follows:

```
(update *test* '(a z) 10)
```

Here is a trace:

```
0: (UPDATE #S(FOO :A #S(BAR :X 0 :Y 0 :Z 0) :B 100 :C "string") (A Z) 10)
  1: (UPDATE #S(BAR :X 0 :Y 0 :Z 0) (Z) 10)
    2: (UPDATE 0 NIL 10)
    2: UPDATE returned 10
  1: UPDATE returned #S(BAR :X 0 :Y 0 :Z 10)
0: UPDATE returned #S(FOO :A #S(BAR :X 0 :Y 0 :Z 10) :B 100 :C "string")
```

In order to generalize, you could accept a function instead of a value, so that you could implement the equivalent of `incf` by partially applying the update function with `#'1+` (the resulting closure would accept a list of *keys*).

Also, you need to generalize the *copy* operation, which is possible with generic functions. Likewise, you could use other kinds of accessors, and replace `slot-value` with a generic `access` function (for which there is a `(setf access)` operation). This generic copy/setf approach could be wasteful, however, if you want to share some data. For example, you only need to copy the part of a list which leads to your data, not the cons cells that are following it.

You could define some facility for defining custom updaters:

```
(defmethod perform-update (new (list list) position)
  (nconc (subseq list 0 position)
         (list new)
         (nthcdr (1+ position) list)))
```

Comment: So, let's say you limit the copying to basic lisp objects (leaving aside CLOS instances), is the essence of the universal copy idea then to write recursive generic methods for each type of basic object?

Comment: @davypough Yes, the default universal copy could make a copy of all the components of a data structure (only one level of copy, the update  function show above does the recursive copy when needed). Note that this will be a problem with circular references.

Answer (score 6):

Common Lisp has no universal copier for the same reason it does not have a built-in printable representation of [CLOS objects](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/07_.htm) (see, e.g., [Saving CLOS objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42334222/850781)): the power of [MOP](http://mop.lisp.se/).

Specifically, object creation can have arbitrary side effects whose replication is hard to guarantee. E.g., define [`initialize-instance`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/07_af.htm) for your class to modify slots based something fluid (e.g., tides or just [`random`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_random.htm)). Then the result of [`make-instance`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/07_a.htm) called with the **same arguments** twice may be **different**. You might argue that this is an argument in favor of a [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html)-style generic copier. However, imagine now a class which does instance accounting (an `:allocation :class` slot which contains a hash table mapping unique ID to instance). Now, the round trip from the copied object via the table will get a **different** object (the original, not the copy) - a major contract violation. And these examples are just the tip of the iceberg.

However, I would not agree that Common Lisp encourages imperative style more than functional style. It merely discourages the style you describe (copy+`setf`). Think about it this way: from the functional POV, a copy is indistinguishable from the original (because everything is immutable).

There are also "small hints" showing a clear preference for functional style.
Observe that the "natural" names
(e.g., [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm)) are reserved
for *non-destructive* functions; the destructive versions
(e.g., [`nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm)) are given
obscure names.

Additionally, [pathnames](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/19_.htm), [characters](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/13_.htm) and [numbers](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/12_.htm) (including composites like [`ratio`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_ratio.htm) and [`complex`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_comple.htm)) are
*immutable*, i.e., all pathname and number functions create new objects (functional style).

Thus, IMO, Common Lisp encourages programmers to use functional style while still making imperative style feasible, in conformance to the slogan "*simple things should be easy, hard things should be possible*".

See also [Kent Pitman's writeup](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/PS/EQUAL.html).

Comment: It looks like you wrote the aforementioned CLOS object reader/writer. (Thank you!) Is there a good example of a limitation for certain kinds of object available?

Comment: Add an `after` method to `make-instance` that modifies the object based on the phase of the moon. Then the object you save will be different from the object you read.